# Read/write a text file without refreshing the page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I writed a tiny php script to read/write a text file, my script works good, but I won't to refresh the page when submit.I know php and jQuery but I never used Ajax.
I tried some scripts in the web but I didn't find what I need, even though I found this script that read the file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.get('line1.txt', function(data) {
   $('h1').html(data);
});
</script>
```

So my question how to read/write a file using php/jquery/ajax in order to  not refreshing the page.

my page's code

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("line1.txt", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
$number = (int) fgets($myfile);
if (isset($_POST["number"])) {
    $number = $number+1;
    $myfile = fopen("line1.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile, $number);
}

?>
<html>
<head>

    <title>LINE 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
            <h1><?= $number; ?></h1>

        <form method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" id="number" name="number" value = "<?= $number; ?>">
            <input type="submit" value = "SUIVANT >>" id="next" name="next"  class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dealing with the same page:
To avoid current refreshing page you have to prevent default `submit` event firing.
js part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input:submit').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $.post(window.location.href, {'number': $("input#number").val()}, function(data) {
         if(data) $("input#number").val(data); 
      });
      return false; // just in case if e.preventDefault() fails
   });

});

</script>
```

modified php part:

```
...
if (isset($_POST["number"])) {
    $number = $number+1;
    $myfile = fopen("line1.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile, $number);
    echo $number;
    return;
}
...
```

Comment: @learner123, be aware that testing with `window.location.href` on external resources(codeshare, jsfiddle)may not go as expected. Try it on local webserver

Comment: I tested it in my local server but I forgot calling jQuery file, and I didn't replace H1 content . that's why it didn't works in first time.

Answer (score 0):

why you don't use `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` ?

in client side :

```
// First see : https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/
// send GET request to server 
// parameters send to server will be data that equals to your input value
// then when server response function will be executed.   
$.get('write.php',{data : $('#number').val()},function(result){
   if(result=='ok'){
      alert('write done!')
   }
})
```

and in write.php :

```
<?php 

if(isset($_GET['data'])){
   // append text to line1.txt file!!!
   file_put_contents('line1.txt',$_GET['data'],FILE_APPEND);
   echo 'ok';
   exit();
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please explain your code by commenting it? I didn't understand your  first script.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [RomanPerekhrest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3185459/romanperekhrest), I modified his code to work the way I need.
I wanted to share the full code:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("line1.txt", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
$number = (int) fgets($myfile);
if (isset($_POST["number"])) {
    $number = $number+1;
    $myfile = fopen("line1.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile, $number);
    echo $number;
    return;
}

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $('input:submit').click(function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              $.post(window.location, {'number': $("input#number").val()}, function(data) {
                 if(data) $("input#number").val(data); 
                 $('h1').html(data);
              });
              return false; // just in case if e.preventDefault() fails
           });

        });

        </script>
        <title>LINE 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
                <h1><?= $number; ?></h1>

            <form method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" id="number" name="number" value = "<?= $number; ?>">
                <input type="submit" value = "SUIVANT >>" id="next" name="next"  class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```